# How to suppress powershell confirmation DBATools New-DbaDbUser

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I'm trying to use the dbatools functions `New-DbaDbUser` and `Add-DbaDbRoleMember` to avoid creating my own version, but struggle to get the confirmation pop up window skipped/suppressed.

I have tried several combinations of `-Force` and `-Confirm` and so on, but nothing seems to be working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it wasn't DbaTools that was raising the confirmation windows hence I have added

```
-Confirm:$false
```

when calling the functions:

```
New-DbaDbUser -SqlInstance $srvNameTarget -Database $dbNameTarget -Login $existingUsers.login[$i] -Username $existingUsers.name[$i] -Confirm:$false

Add-DbaDbRoleMember -SqlInstance $srvNameTarget -Database $dbNameTarget -Role $RoleMembers[$j].Role -User $exisitngUsers.name[$i] -Confirm:$false
```

And this resolved the issue and I no longer get prompt for confirmation! Yay!!!